# How to tell a widget to stay in one GUI

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

So i am trying to make a pop up GUI for a program I am making and i have been testing different methods.  The problem is that the widgets I create all go to the first GUI I created is there a way to tell what GUI the widget is going to be on.

```
from Tkinter import *

def sailors ():
    Root = Tk ()
    Root.title ('Error')
    info = Label (text = 'Fire')
    info.grid (row = 0, column = 0)
    you = Button (text = "OK", command = sys.exit )
    info.grid (row = 1, column = 0)
    Root.mainloop ()

root1 = Tk ()
YES= Button (text = 'Coolio', command = sailors )
YES.pack ()
root1.mainloop ()
```

Comment: `info = Label (Root, text = 'Fire')` ? http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm#Tkinter.Label-class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter when creating a widget specifies the parent.

```
root = Tk()
info = Label(root, ...)
you = Button(root, ...)
```

**However**, in your code you are creating two instances of `Tk`. Tkinter isn't designed to work like that. You should only ever create exactly one instance of `Tk`, and call `mainloop()` exactly once. If you need multiple windows, every window but the first should be an instance of `Toplevel`.

Comment: Thank you it is exactly what I was looking for